# QT Using stylesheets to increase size of slider handle

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QT to subclass QSlider and now I want to make the handle larger. I used SetStylesheet and set a background color and the new size. When running, the color is set but the size seems to be fixed. I can however adjust the size of the whole QSlider: in that case the groove with handle stays the same size but the surround widget area becomes larger.

How can I fix this? And furthermore, is there an overview somewhere of the components each QWidget has with a reference to how they can be adjusted by stylesheets?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be setting a negative margin in the stylesheet of the handle of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change handel size:

aSliderProxy = new SliderProxy();
ui->materialVerticalSlider->setStyle(aSliderProxy);

File sliderproxy.h:
#ifndef SLIDERPROXY_H
#define SLIDERPROXY_H

#include <QProxyStyle>

class SliderProxy : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    int pixelMetric ( PixelMetric metric, const QStyleOption * option = 0, const QWidget * widget = 0 ) const
    {
        switch(metric) {
        case PM_SliderThickness  : return 50;
        case PM_SliderLength     : return 50;
        default                         : return (QProxyStyle::pixelMetric(metric,option,widget));
        }
    }
};
#endif // SLIDERPROXY_H
```

Comment: Even if not using stylesheets like requested by the question, +1 for useful solution by code.